# How to use private blockchains in ethereumjs-tx@2.1.2?

Tags: transactions, private-blockchain, ethereumjs, ethereumjs-tx

I know this method

```
var transaction = new Tx(rawTransaction, {chain:'ropsten'});
```

I tried

```
var transaction = new Tx(rawTransaction, {chain:'192.168.XX.XX:8545'});
```

But get Error: Chain with name 192.168.XX.XX:8545 not supported

Any help with this is much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: that's not a chaid id, that's a connection string.

Comment: Please edit your title. I do not find any link between it and your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this way :

```
    const EthereumTx = require('ethereumjs-tx').Transaction;
    import Common from 'ethereumjs-common';

        const customCommon = Common.forCustomChain(
        'mainnet',
        {
            name: 'my-private-blockchain',
            networkId: NETWORK_ID,
            chainId: CHAIN_ID,
        },
        'istanbul',
    );

    const tx = new EthereumTx(txParams, { common: customCommon });
```

With CHAIN_ID and NETWORK_ID numbers.

Here is the full exemple from the official documentation : https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx/blob/master/examples/custom-chain-tx.ts .